# Make error inside `try` not handled by `catch`

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, error-handling

I want the specific errors that are thrown inside `try` block not to be handled by `catch(err)`

Example:

```
const someFunc = async () => {
  ...
  try {
    ...
    // This error should not be handled by the catch and go straight to the middleware
    throw {
      status: 404,
      message: "Not Found",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw {
      status: 500,
      message: "Something went wrong",
      reason: error,
    };
  }
};
```

After that the middleware handles the errors.

```
export const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const { status = 500, message, reason } = err;
  res.status(status).json({
    success: false,
    message: message || "Something went wrong",
    reason: reason || undefined,
  });
};
```

Comment: Not quite possible, I don't think. You could create a custom error function that passes the error to your middleware, but you can't directly throw inside a try catch block without being uncaught.

Comment: you can implement multiple catch blocks to handle different types of errors. see: [Conditional catch-blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#conditional_catch-blocks)

Comment: Nothing _requires_ you to throw an instance of [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/error), but you should in your code. See express docs on error-handling: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you throw an error inside a `try`-block, the `catch` will catch it. The best you can do is to check in the `catch`-block if the error you don't want to catch is thrown and if so, rethrow it.

```js
const someFunc = async () => {
  try {
    throw {
      status: 404,
      message: "Not Found",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // If a 404 error is caught, rethrow it.
    if (error.status === 404) {
      throw error;
    }

    throw {
      status: 500,
      message: "Something went wrong",
      reason: error,
    };
  }
};
```